# Regression with discrete targets

Tags: regression, classification, scikit-learn

The model I train is used to predict a quasi-continuous target variable (e.g. a time). The predicted time can be used to calculate a resulting score, but this is computationally expensive. I precomputed scores for discrete times that I can look up, however, the output from the regression is continuous. Can I force the regression to 'choose' a discrete time or do I have to use a classifier?

The disadvantage of the classifier would be that I does not understand that e.g. class `2s` is smaller than class `3s` and bigger than class `1s`.
The framework is sklearn for now, using a decision tree regressor.

Comment: But if a regression predicts a continuous time, don't you just know in which discrete time it belongs?

Comment: It seems that by "quasi-continuous" you may be mean "ordinal" variable? Please provide more details about the variables & the model you mention in your question.

Comment: @rep_ho The regression likes to predict 2.54s if it cannot distinguish the 2s and 3s, but the score difference between 2s and 3s is quite big. So I would want to force it to choose one.

Comment: @dipetkov yes, I mean ordinal. The variable is used as a parameter for a computational expensive simulation and I can only compute the score in discrete intervals and the regression would need to choose one of them. Otherwise, can I let the classifier know that the variable is ordinal?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it may have too much labels if using classifier, and since it is quasi-continuous, so regression may get better performance since it use more information than classification. Maybe you can try get the prediction from the regression and transform them based on distance to nearby targets to be discrete, like 1.02s -> 1s since 1.02 is more close to 1s than 2s.

Comment: There are not too many labels (~10), but it is indeed quasi-continuous and that I why I wanted to use regression. Now if the regression cannot distinguish 2s and 3s it predicts 2.54s, which seems to yield the best performance.

Comment: Yeah, sounds great. I think sometimes regression works better in this situation. Or you could try multi-label classification and compare with regression if you have enough time.